# multiplicative inverse with lookup table

Tags: c, math, arm

I have an formula that I use multiple times in my subroutine, but my processor does not have division instruction(M0), so this is handled by the software library. To speed up this operation, I am considering using a lookup table to store the result of the inverse. However that would still take up 2kb in space (2 bytes per value). How can I optimize it further?

Formula is as follows, k is a constant known at compile time k = [10, 100]. x = [0, 1023]

(1000 * k) * ((1023/x) - 1)

EDITE: Clarification about precision. Since I have the "1000", I am considering using the result of the multiplication by 1000 to increase precision.

Comment: What is the range of values for k? What is the domain—reals, integers modulo some number, what? What accuracy is required?

Comment: I upto two decimal points should be acceptable. I am considering storing the result of the multiplication by 1000 to increase precision.

Comment: k is positive integer number 10 to 100

Comment: So, for “two decimal points,” if k is 100 and x is 1, you would have 1000•100•(1023/1−1) = 102,200,000, so results from 102,199,999.995 to 102,200,000.005 would be acceptable and anything outside that would not? You want accuracy up to one part in 2•10^10?

Comment: Is `1000*k*((1023/x)-1)` supposed to be computed with integer arithmetic, so `1023/x` is truncated to an integer before the subtraction and multiplications are performed, or is all the work done as if on real numbers, and then the final result is rounded to something? To what, to an integer, to two decimal points, something else?

Comment: An ARM processor with `clz` can do a division pretty quickly with a jump on number of significant digits and a set of 3 instructions per bit.  Depending on the size of the numbers, a table may or may not be faster.

Comment: If you multiply by 1024, you have basically created a fixed point number with 10 bits of fraction...

Comment: If you posted the exact ARM CPU, others may be able to give more detailed advice.

Comment: processor is M0

Comment: @EricPostpischil I meant precision for the 1023/x operation. For example 1023/701 = 1.459 and 1023/702 = 1.457. So if I pull in the * 1000 operation I will get 1459 and 1457 that I can store.

Comment: hey guys, there is no `clz` on the M0 unless you implement it in software.

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming `/` is integer division**

You don't need to store 1024 values, because many values of `x` result in the same value of `1023/x`.

Specifically:

```
x:      [   1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,   10,   11,   12,   13,   14,   15,   16,   17,   18,   19,   20,   21,   22,   23,   24,   25,   26,   27,   28,   29,   30,   31,   33,   34,   35,   36,   37,   39,   40,   42,   44,   46,   48,   51,   53,   56,   60,   63,   68,   73,   78,   85,   93,  102,  113,  127,  146,  170,  204,  255,  341,  511, 1023]
1023/x: [1023,  511,  341,  255,  204,  170,  146,  127,  113,  102,   93,   85,   78,   73,   68,   63,   60,   56,   53,   51,   48,   46,   44,   42,   40,   39,   37,   36,   35,   34,   33,   31,   30,   29,   28,   27,   26,   25,   24,   23,   22,   21,   20,   19,   18,   17,   16,   15,   14,   13,   12,   11,   10,    9,    8,    7,    6,    5,    4,    3,    2,    1]
```

You need only to store these 62 values of x and the 62 results of 1023/x.

As a bonus: if you look carefully, you'll notice those values are symmetric. The values for x are the exact mirror of the values for 1023/x. So you only need to store one of these two arrays.

Comment: That is interesting yes. I am considering storing the result of multiplication by 1000 to increase precision.

Comment: If you increase the precision too much, you'll have to store all 1023 values as there won't be duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily shrink the lookup table to 256*2 bytes

```
static inline uint16_t get1023divxminus1(uint16_t x)
{
    static const uint16_t table[256] = {0, 1022, 510, ....., 3};
    if (x >= 512) return 0;
    if (x >= 342) return 1;
    if (x >= 256) return 2;
    return table[x];
}
```

You could shrink the table even further, but I think it isn't worth the additional `if`s.

Answer (score 0):

You could compress the data in the table.

For example by storing full 2-byte values for every N-th value of `x` and store difference values for `x`s in between. The difference should fit in 1 byte in many cases.

If N would be 4, you'd store full values for x: 0, 4, 8, ... and difference values for x: 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, ...

To get the result for say x == 3, start with 2-byte value of 0 and add the 1-byte difference values of 1 and 2.

There will for sure be other 'tricks' to play if you'd have a close look at the data and think in the direction of data compression.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing RAM is probably going to be slower than calculating long division, as long as your values fit within a register. In principle, calculating long division should be linear in the number of bits. Implement both and profile, but I am highly convinced that long division will be faster:

The algorithms is:
left shift the divisor until the MSD of the divisor equals the MSD of the dividend.

If the divisor is smaller than the dividend, write one, else write 0. Right shift the divisor by one. Repeat until the LSD of the divisor is also the LSD of the dividend.

Here is an explicit implementation:
https://codegolf.stackexchangechaschastitytity.com/questions/24541/divide-two-numbers-using-long-division

Comment: Division on ARM takes about 26 cycles while a L1 cache hit only takes 3 cycles. At the size of LUT that fits into 32kb, LUT is way faster.

Comment: Only if and when the LUT is already in the cache. But that might not be the case, if you do enough operations and accesses in between division, the LUT might not be in the cache, and if you have to load it from RAM it will 100% be slower, which is why I mentioned loading from RAM in my answer, and why I prompted OP to profile his use case to make sure a LUT actually does work better than long division.

Comment: The kind of ARM processor that doesn't have hardware division will typically be a microcontroller with fast integrated RAM, without any cache at all.

Comment: @Makogan L1 cache miss results in a penalty of about 23 cycles, still shorter than division.